# Why is Babel not transpiling my React app import?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I've setup a React app using CRA, and then also an Express (generator) server where I'm supposed to do some SSR.

My current folder is kind of this:

```
app/
  public/
  src/ (React application source files)
  server/ (Express)
    .babelrc
    src/ (Source files for Express server)
      bin/
        www
      middleware/
        serverRenderer.js
      ...
      app.js
```

I have the following Babel packages installed:

```
"@babel/cli": "^7.2.0",
"@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
"@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0",
"@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
"babel-preset-react-app-babel-7": "^4.0.2-0"
```

I run the Express server using the following command:

```
"server:dev": "NODE_ENV=development PORT=3001 nodemon ./server/src/bin/www --exec babel-node"
```

My custom middleware, `serverRenderer.js` has the following code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import App from '../../../src/App';

module.exports = function(req, res, next){
    console.log("Middleware to render React app...!")
    next();
}
```

The file `www` (inside bin/) starts with:

```
require('ignore-styles');
require('@babel/register');
```

When I start up the Express server, my middleware is being called, and right away I'm getting this error, pointing on my JSX code.. 
`App.js: Unexpected token`

What is going on here? I can't figure out why this is not working, what am I missing?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Providing more info.

`App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you paste your `App.js` code??

Comment: Updated with App.js code @HarishSoni

Comment: Try to rename `App.js` to `App.jsx`. Depending on your setup it's also possible you have to specify presets somewhere.

Comment: Yes @Sulthan said it correct try changing it to the `.jsx`

Comment: @Sulthan nope, doesn't matter. Same error.

Comment: Check https://hackernoon.com/full-stack-web-application-using-react-node-js-express-and-webpack-97dbd5b9d708 and the section about `.babelrc`. That's probably the problem.